# Find the period

Tags: functions

I was solving the following question:

> Find the period of $\min\{\sin x, |x|\}$.

My solution is: $\min\{\sin x, |x|\}=\sin x$. Hence period is $2\pi$.

Is my solution correct?

Comment: Seems correct to me.

Comment: Yes  , But prove min{sin(x),|x|)=sin(x)

Comment: $f(x)=x-\sin x$ is an increasing function for $x\geq 0$ as $f'(x)\geq 0$. Hence $\sin x\leq x$